# Relation between imageJ blur radius and OpenCV Gaussian Blur sigma

Tags: opencv, imagej

I am trying to blur a `ROI` in an image using `Gaussian filter` and `imageJ` software.

I am getting the desired result with `blur radius as 9` in `imageJ`.

Now I am trying to write the corresponding `OpenCV C++ application` to do same operations which I did with `imageJ`.

The `Gaussian Blur` signature in `openCV` is as below:

`C++: void GaussianBlur(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, Size ksize, double sigmaX, double sigmaY=0, int borderType=BORDER_DEFAULT )`

What is the `sigmaX` and `sigmaY` corresponding to `ImageJ blur radius of 9`?

I tried many resources such as:
[Blur Radius](https://dbaron.org/log/20110225-blur-radius)

but I am not getting the same results with `OpenCV`.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please elaborate on how the results are "not the same" ?

The blur radius in ImageJ is defined as  "'Radius' means the radius of decay to exp(-0.5) ~ 61%, i.e. the standard deviation sigma of the Gaussian" (coming from ImageJ documentation : https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/plugin/filter/GaussianBlur.html#GaussianBlur--)
I see no reason why it should not be implemented the same way in OpenCV.

However, I also observe these differences between ImageJ and OpenCV gaussian blur.
While for the moment I have no solution to make these absolutely the same, I managed to get them closer, and can see one potential difference and one difference for sure in implementation :

**Kernel size** (potential difference) :
Are you aware that kernel size and gaussian radius are two different things ? Kernel size is the size of the kernel applied to the image (3*3, 5*5 etc), but inside this kernel a gaussian with any radius can theroetically exist. However, kernel size is often chosed such that on the kernel borders, the gaussian function has decayed to about zero.

This being said, ImageJ automatically choses the kernel for you depending on the radius you chose, in order to fulfill the "gaussian decays to zero on borders" condition. The OpenCV function also does that if you set sigma to your desired radius and ksize as zero. The question is "do they both do it the same way ?".

ImageJ's implementation of this is trickier than you might think : "In ImageJ, the size of the kernel actually used depends on the accuracy
needed:  With sigma=1, for 16-bit and float images the kernel is 9 pixels
wide (which gives 9x9 for a 2D image), but for 8-bit or RGB images is is
only 7 pixels wide because there is no need for a very high accuracy if
there are only 256 different values. For large values of sigma, the situation is more complex: For sigma >=8, the data are first downscaled, then the Gaussian Blur is applied, and interpolation is used for upscaling to the original number of data points. The downscaling and interpolation algorithms are specially designed for best accuracy.", etc etc (coming from the "ImageJ forum", I can't post the link since I don't have enough reputation, but just google this quote if you want the source)

I do not know if OpenCV does such operations or if it computes the kernel size differently, thus giving different results. (couldn't find it with Google).

**Borders** (difference for sure) : As you probably know, the gaussian filter goes over every pixel in the image and computes a new value for this pixel based on its neighbors. But what about the pixels close to the borders, where the gaussian kernel is wider than their distance from the image's border ? How do algorithms handle it ? By inspecting my images closer, I found that the main differences between the OCV implementation and the IJ one were on the border pixels.

Well it turns out ImageJ and OpenCV handle these pixels differently :

ImageJ gaussian, "Like all convolution operations in ImageJ, it assumes that out-of-image pixels have a value equal to the nearest edge pixel." (from same ImageJ doc than above).

However, OpenCV lets you chose other options, and the default one, called `BORDER_DEFAULT` in the OpenCV call, is `BORDER_REFLECT_101` (http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html) (at least I think it is, it is the default border for another method using borders, so I would think it is also the default border for the gaussian). `BORDER_REFLECT_101` sort of "mirrors" the borders (gfedcb|abcdefgh, see link).

To get closer to ImageJ (aaaaaaaa|abcdefgh), use `BORDER_DEFAULT=BORDER_REPLICATE`. With this, I get closer results between the two implementations (though not exactly the same, I will keep investigating and edit my answer if I find more clues).

[Note : I am working in Python2.7 (not C++) and OpenCV 3, but I don't think it has an impact on this problem]